# How to remove a "document" in MongoDB using MongoVUE?

Tags: mongodb, user-interface, jit, mongovue

I'm trying to remove an object on my mongodb using mongovue, but I keep getting the following error. Please help and let me know what I'm doing wrong?

I right click on the document, hit 'Remove', and I get a window with this:

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
MongoDB.Driver.MongoSafeModeException: Safemode detected an error 'need to login'. (response was { "errmsg" : "need to login", "ok" : 0.0 }).
   at MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoConnection.SendMessage(MongoRequestMessage message, SafeMode safeMode)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection.Remove(IMongoQuery query, RemoveFlags flags, SafeMode safeMode)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection.Remove(IMongoQuery query, SafeMode safeMode)
   at MangoUI.MCollections.Remove(String db, String col, BsonDocument q, Boolean safe)
   at MangoUI.MCollections.Remove(MConnection con, String db, String col, BsonDocument q, Boolean safe)
   at MangoUI.MCollections.Remove(IMCollection col, BsonDocument q, Boolean safe)
   at MangoUI.MBsonData.RemoveAll(IMCollection coll)
   at MangoUI.ComBsonTree.kRemoveIt_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.KryptonContextMenuItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.KryptonContextMenuItem.PerformClick()
   at do.c()
   at do.a(Control A_0, Point A_1, MouseButtons A_2)
   at ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.ViewBase.MouseUp(Point pt, MouseButtons button)
   at ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.ViewBase.MouseUp(Point pt, MouseButtons button)
   at ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.ViewBase.MouseUp(Point pt, MouseButtons button)
   at ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.ViewManager.MouseUp(MouseEventArgs e, Point rawPt)
   at ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.VisualPopup.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.VisualPopup.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5466 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
MongoVUE
    Assembly Version: 1.5.3.0
    Win32 Version: 1.5.3.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/MongoVUE/MongoVUE%201.5.3/MongoVUE.exe
----------------------------------------
BitFactory.Logging
    Assembly Version: 1.5.2.0
    Win32 Version: 1.5.2.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/MongoVUE/MongoVUE%201.5.3/BitFactory.Logging.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5468 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5467 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5467 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit
    Assembly Version: 4.3.2.0
    Win32 Version: 4.3.2.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/MongoVUE/MongoVUE%201.5.3/ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Management
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Management/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Management.dll
----------------------------------------
DevExpress.Utils.v10.2
    Assembly Version: 10.2.8.0
    Win32 Version: 10.2.8.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/MongoVUE/MongoVUE%201.5.3/DevExpress.Utils.v10.2.DLL
----------------------------------------
MongoDB.Bson
    Assembly Version: 1.3.1.4349
    Win32 Version: 1.3.1.4349
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/MongoVUE/MongoVUE%201.5.3/MongoDB.Bson.DLL
----------------------------------------
DevExpress.XtraTreeList.v10.2
    Assembly Version: 10.2.8.0
    Win32 Version: 10.2.8.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/MongoVUE/MongoVUE%201.5.3/DevExpress.XtraTreeList.v10.2.DLL
----------------------------------------
MongoDB.Driver
    Assembly Version: 1.3.1.4349
    Win32 Version: 1.3.1.4349
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/MongoVUE/MongoVUE%201.5.3/MongoDB.Driver.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5459 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
QWhale.Editor
    Assembly Version: 1.62.4104.36377
    Win32 Version: 1.62.4104.36377
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/MongoVUE/MongoVUE%201.5.3/QWhale.Editor.DLL
----------------------------------------
ComponentFactory.Krypton.Navigator
    Assembly Version: 4.3.2.0
    Win32 Version: 4.3.2.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/MongoVUE/MongoVUE%201.5.3/ComponentFactory.Krypton.Navigator.DLL
----------------------------------------
ComponentFactory.Krypton.Docking
    Assembly Version: 4.3.2.0
    Win32 Version: 4.3.2.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/MongoVUE/MongoVUE%201.5.3/ComponentFactory.Krypton.Docking.DLL
----------------------------------------
ComponentFactory.Krypton.Workspace
    Assembly Version: 4.3.2.0
    Win32 Version: 4.3.2.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/MongoVUE/MongoVUE%201.5.3/ComponentFactory.Krypton.Workspace.DLL
----------------------------------------
Argotic.Core
    Assembly Version: 2008.0.2.0
    Win32 Version: 2008.0.2.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/MongoVUE/MongoVUE%201.5.3/Argotic.Core.DLL
----------------------------------------
Argotic.Common
    Assembly Version: 2008.0.2.0
    Win32 Version: 2008.0.2.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/MongoVUE/MongoVUE%201.5.3/Argotic.Common.DLL
----------------------------------------
Argotic.Extensions
    Assembly Version: 2008.0.2.0
    Win32 Version: 2008.0.2.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/MongoVUE/MongoVUE%201.5.3/Argotic.Extensions.DLL
----------------------------------------
zrhbhik5
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5467 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
Renci.SshNet
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/MongoVUE/MongoVUE%201.5.3/Renci.SshNet.DLL
----------------------------------------
DevExpress.XtraEditors.v10.2
    Assembly Version: 10.2.8.0
    Win32 Version: 10.2.8.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/MongoVUE/MongoVUE%201.5.3/DevExpress.XtraEditors.v10.2.DLL
----------------------------------------
DevExpress.Data.v10.2
    Assembly Version: 10.2.8.0
    Win32 Version: 10.2.8.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/MongoVUE/MongoVUE%201.5.3/DevExpress.Data.v10.2.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 3.5.0.0
    Win32 Version: 3.5.30729.5420 built by: Win7SP1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
WindowsBase
    Assembly Version: 3.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 3.0.6920.5448 built by: Win7SP1GDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/WindowsBase/3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/WindowsBase.dll
----------------------------------------
QWhale.Common
    Assembly Version: 1.62.4104.36375
    Win32 Version: 1.62.4104.36375
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/MongoVUE/MongoVUE%201.5.3/QWhale.Common.DLL
----------------------------------------
QWhale.Syntax
    Assembly Version: 1.62.4104.36376
    Win32 Version: 1.62.4104.36376
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/MongoVUE/MongoVUE%201.5.3/QWhale.Syntax.DLL
----------------------------------------
QWhale.Syntax.Schemes
    Assembly Version: 1.62.4104.36378
    Win32 Version: 1.62.4104.36378
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/MongoVUE/MongoVUE%201.5.3/QWhale.Syntax.Schemes.DLL
----------------------------------------
v1zaffjg
    Assembly Version: 1.62.4104.36376
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5467 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

Comment: Btw, I have Windows 7 x64, running MongoVUE 1.5.3.0.

Comment: Do you have authentication enabled in MongoDB?  The 'need to login' sticks out.  Of course MongoVUE has been abandoned, so there is probably little chance of it getting fixed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mongo::OperationFailure - need to login when using from\_uri](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15562279/mongooperationfailure-need-to-login-when-using-from-uri)